# Entity unable to save foreign key Entities

Tags: java, jpa

My `Content` has a Map of `Footnote`, and `Footnote` has a `content_id` column which is a foreign key back to `Content`.  Unfortunately saving my `Content` with the `footnoteMap` containing a `Footnote` throws the following error:

```
ERROR: Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'content_id', table 'CMT_DEV.dbo.footnote'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.
SEVERE: org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'content_id', table 'CMT_DEV.dbo.footnote'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.; SQL [n/a]; constraint [null]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'content_id', table 'CMT_DEV.dbo.footnote'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.
```

I must be missing something with the annotations required to make this work, but I can't figure out what it is.

Here is my JPA mapping:

```
public class Content implements EntityModel, Serializable {
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="contentId", cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    @MapKey(name="number")
    @OrderBy("number ASC")
    private Map<Integer, Footnote> footnoteMap;

    ....
}

public class Footnote implements EntityModel, Serializable {
    @ManyToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "content_id", referencedColumnName= "id")
    private Content contentId;

    ....
}
```

*** update ***

Keep in mind that the point at which a `Footnote` is added, the content item has not been saved.

Comment: Is Content meant to have "contentId" but Footnote have "content_id", just a shot in the dark.

Comment: How are the id's set/generated/annotated?

Comment: Have you tried explicitelly telling that tha ManyToOne column is optional?:
@ManyToOne(optional=true, cascade=CascadeType.ALL); And also check if even after this the column in the database does not have a not null constraint

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, note that it's your responsibility to keep both sides of bidirectional relationships in consitent state, i.e. when you add a `Footnote` to `Content` you should also set its `contentId` appropriately.

If you did so but it still fails, then perhaps it's a mismatch between database schema and Hibernate mapping. Note that `content_id` column has a not null constraint, but nothing in the mapping tells Hibernate that such a constraint exists. Try `@ManyToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, optional = false)`.

Comment: The point at which a `Footnote` item is added to a `Content` the `Content` does not have an ID.

Comment: @Webnet: It doesn't matter, type of `contextId` field is `Content` and you should assign that `Content`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have something like this...

```
public void addFootnote(Footnote footnote) {
    if (footnote == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Null argument not allowed");
    }
    footnote.setContent(this);
    footNoteMap.put(<KEY_OF_MAP>, footnote);
}
```

which will make sure that `content` is populated for `Footnote` instance.

Comment: This doesn't help the content ID get set in the footnote.